# Separating comma separated values in a string

Tags: java, csv, delimiter

```
String company = "general%20motors,ibm%20watson";
```

I have a string in the above format which is separated with **comma**. My requirement is to pass general%20motors individually. In the same way ibm%20watson afterwards. So any sugggestions how can we proceed ?

Comment: What's the language? Add it to the tag.

Comment: What language are you using? From the syntax above, it could be C++ or Java for starters.

Comment: Does [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) work for you? It would just be: `String companies[] = company.split(",");`.

Answer (score 3):

If your `company` string has many values seperated by commas:-

```
String company="general%20motors,ibm%20watson";

    String arr[]=company.split(",");
    for(String string2:arr)
      System.out.println(string2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the code below:

```
String company = "general%20motors,ibm%20watson";
String tokens[] = company.split("[,]");
System.out.println(tokens[0]);
System.out.println(tokens[1]);
```

The above code displays:

```
general%20motors
ibm%20watson
```

Comment: Can you fix your array element access it's `tokens[i]` not `tokens(i)`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it seems like JAVA.

---

Use we have string tokenizer in Java just provide StringTokenizer and pass the data in to it as a streamed buffer and put ",(comma)" as a delimiter.Required output will come.you can use MIME type to get recognize the csv.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it.
Here are all possible ways I know: split, Stringtokenizer, Apache commons StringUtils and Guava Splitter.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import com.google.common.base.Splitter;

public class Split {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String company = "general%20motors,ibm%20watson";
        final String delimiter = ",";

        System.out.print("using core java split method    : ");
        String[] tokens = company.split(delimiter);
        for (String s : tokens) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("using core java StringTokenizer : ");
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(company, delimiter);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            System.out.print(st.nextToken() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("using apache commons StringUtils: ");
        tokens = StringUtils.split(company, delimiter);
        for (String s : tokens) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("using guava Splitter            : ");
        Iterable<String> tkns = Splitter.on(delimiter).split(company);
        for (String s : tkns) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
    }
}
```